# Android WebView Not Loading

Tags: java, android, webview

I am programming an application in Java that consists of a menu with multiple selections each bringing you to a view with a webview and a back button. My webviews are currently not displaying the URL I have put in. However I am not recieving any errors in my logcat and my program seems to be running correctly other than the webviews just staying blank. Here is my code:

```
package com.fox.hipnyc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);




            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

            }



        });}}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please show your layout?

Comment: Do you want your `Webview` to show immediately or just when you click the `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not seeing anything because you are only calling load when you click the back `Button`. You have to call it from outside your `Button` `onclick()` method. Like this:

```
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

     WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

After that change, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the internet permission set in the manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Yes I have internet permission set